# Resetting Values using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, reset

Trying to reset value of input to blank using button and jquery, but it gives

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).reset is not a function

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#reset_btn").click(function() {
    $("#buy").reset();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" class="form-control" id="buy" placeholder="Buy Amount" name="buy">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="reset_btn">RESET</button>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option to remove the value of input is to use `.val("")`. Basically setting the value to an empty string.

Here is an example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#reset_btn").click(function() {
    $("#buy").val("");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" class="form-control" id="buy" placeholder="Buy Amount" name="buy">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="reset_btn">RESET</button>
```

Comment: Run https://jsfiddle.net/hgf8x4b7/, why `#tot_amnt` is being reset after clicking twice the reset button?

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Does multiple loading of php file (no database connection in it) causes high CPU Usage?

Comment: Happy to help. On your other question, It depends on the file you are loading and the processes that it is doing. You have to monitor your app/site for that one :)

Answer (score 2):

As the error message clearly states, `reset()` is not a jQuery method. You'll want to call the native form element's `reset()` instead. For this, of course, you'll need a form element in the first place.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#reset_btn").click(function() {
    $("#form")[0].reset();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="form">
  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="buy" placeholder="Buy Amount" name="buy">

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="reset_btn">RESET</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Your answer also worked but my input tag was not in the form, that's why accepted Eddie's answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#buy').val('');
```

Clear the value instead of using reset.